# Daemon errors when building application

Tags: java, flutter, gradle, daemon

These problems just came out of the blue as for yesterday everything was working fine, today I was trying to debug my flutter app when this error showed up

[image: error1 part 1]
[image: error1 part 2]

I even made a new flutter project just to be sure it has nothing to do with my code, and tried to run the flutter starters app, but I still got the same error.

Not only that I noticed strange behavior when I opened the task manager.

[image: task manager]
[image: task manager]

I have absolutely no idea what went wrong and what's not working, I tried to restart my pc several times with no success. **This happened to me before!** But I thought it was due to slow internet connection at the time my internet was barely useable, when my internet connection got better it worked again, **however this is not the case this time** my connection is stable and fast so I have no clue where this is coming from. Trying to build it multiple times **every time I get a different error.**

Like this:
[image: error 2]

And this:
[image: error 3]

If someone could tell me what's going on and how to fix this, since I'm completely clueless.
Any info would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try to rebuild project and load it from directory again :)

Comment: Screenshots of code and errors [don't constitute an MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Comment: @Zoe  I used screenshots because at the time I got these problems stack overflow was down, and everything is working again like normal without me changing anything so the only way to show the errors would be to write them by hand, it has nothing to do with my code as stated in the question so I think your decision to close this question was a bit too fast judged for this case. All I want to learn is what is causing this error which comes and leaves by itself

Answer (score 0):

`gradle --stop` suppose to stop all daemons .

2nd you can try to add `_JAVA_OPTIONS : -Xmx1024M` to your gradle.properties

and lastly you can try to manually stop them manually and try again . this look bad but it should work .